# Is there a paid or free service to help travelers right to the gate?

Tags: honduras

My mom is traveling to Honduras on the 29th of March. She does not speak any English, so she needs somebody to take her to her gate. Would be helpful for her to get someone to take her. What would it cost?

Comment: at which airport are you hoping to find this service?

Comment: Usually it is not necessary to know English. Just know the destination (and maybe about the word *gate*). Depending the airline and the airport, the people after them in queue will go to the same destination, so she (or you) can coordinate with them. On hub airports (for specific airlines) it will not work. -- Also: try to contact airline. The *special needs" may offer such service for free -- but are you sure she cannot go alone?

Comment: Further to @KateGregory's comment, many airports in the US have signs in Spanish, and I would guess that in most of the major international airports you will have no trouble finding someone who speaks Spanish; in some of them I suppose a majority of the staff probably speak the language.  I suppose that airlines are likely to assign Spanish speaking gate staff to flights to Latin America, so she should be able to ask those people for help.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi in my experience, airlines do not typically challenge requests for such services, so it may be unnecessary to be certain that she can't handle it by herself.  My mother in law speaks very little English, so we've taken to booking the "mobility service" for her even though she doesn't really need a wheelchair.  The first time we did this it was at the airline's suggestion when we were worried about a tight connection because of the language barrier.

Comment: What airport, and what airline? Depending on the circumstances, you could get service from the airline, directly from the airport, or even get a gate pass to allow you to accompany her to the gate yourself. But I agree with others that most people can navigate airports without speaking a word of English, and in many places in the US, Spanish will be quite prevalent, not only on signs, but among staff and other passengers.

Comment: Please edit in the airports (or at least the countries) involved for which she would need help.